# Selenium Page Factory How.Custom C# Examples

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone using C# with Selenium's PageFactory know how to implement a How.Custom locator? I have searched the internet high and low to no avail. All examples are in java and even those seem to be far and few between.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class like:

```cs
public class NgByModelFinder : By
{
    public NgByModelFinder(string locator)
    {
        FindElementMethod = (ISearchContext context) => context.FindElement(NgBy.Model(locator));
    }
}
```

and then attach FindsBy attribute with your webelement like:

```cs
[FindsBy(How = How.Custom, Using = "value for locator", CustomFinderType = typeof(NgByModelFinder))]
protected IWebElement TestDiv { get; set; }
```

I hope the above will help you.